# Load testing a tomcat 7 server - error 503 service unavailble

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, testing, load

We created an automated script in order to load test our server.
We created 100 simultanious users that work against the server via http request to a spring web app controllers. (via restTemplate)

that worked pretty well.

When we tried to increase the number of simultanious users to 200 some of the requests recieve a

```
503 Service Unavailable
```

I tried to set my max connection on the tomcat to 1000

when i enter the manager app to see the server status on real time while load testing i see the following line:

```
Max threads: 1000 Current thread count: 60 Current thread busy: 35
```

The current thread is not exceeding 60 for some reason and the current thread busy is not exceeding 35.

Any ideas what can we do to determine the reason for that?

Comment: You probably reached the thread limits of tomcat.

Comment: You problably reached the number of simultanious user that can be handled by you application. -- You need some profiling tool to find the bottlenack.

Comment: Trying to set maxThreads=500 on each tomcat (got 2 of them) will report soon

Comment: Ok, lets wait for result :-)

Comment: Ok i found the problem - it was my proxy before the tomcat.